# Get a list of components and their props from MDX string - by regex?

Tags: reactjs, parsing, jsx

### My problem - Get components & props from MDX/JSX string

I have an [MDX](https://mdxjs.com/) string with [Front-matter meta data](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/) in YAML, some regular text, some markdown and some React components.

I need to get the list of all React (non-HTML) components from it with their parameters.

So given this example:

```
---
title: Title of documents
tags: one, two, three
---

# My heading H1

Some text in paragraph. Than the list:
 - First item
 - Second item

More text with [a link](https://example.com).

<Articles category="theatre" count={3} />

Further text with more information.

<Newsletter categories={['theatre', 'design']} />

<MultilineComponent 
  paramA="A"
  paramB="B"
/>

<ComponentWithChildren param="value">
  Some children
</ComponentWithChildren>
```

... I would need this output:

```js
[
  {
    component: 'Articles',
    props: {
      category: 'theatre',
      count: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    component: 'Newsletter',
    props: {
      categories: ['theatre', 'design'],
    }
  },
  {
    component: 'MultilineComponent',
    props: {
      paramA: 'A',
      paramB: 'B',
    }
  },
  {
    component: 'ComponentWithChildren',
    props: {
      param: 'value',
    }

  }
]
```

Also I need to do this on the server, so I don't have access to browser functionality (window, document, etc.).

### What I've tried

Some basic Regex, but as I'm far from being professional in regexing, [now I have two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247). :)

Is there some built in way how to parse JSX string to get a list of components & props in the way that I've described above? Or is there some maybe some other parser that I can use to solve this? If not, is there some Regex pattern I can use to get this?

### Quick summary on "Why"

During the build of my Next.js project I need to determine which data is actually needed for each MDX page in the bundle. So if I see this in the Mdx file:

```
...other text

<Articles category="theatre" count={3} />

...other text
```

... which I'm somehow able to parse to this:

```
component: "Articles"
category: "theatre"
count: 3
```

that's enough info for me to know that I need to send those data to the page:

```
[
  {
    title: 'Romeo and Juliet',
    category: 'theatre',
  },
  {
    title: 'The Cherry Orchard',
    category: 'theatre',
  },
  {
    title: 'Death of a Salesman',
    category: 'theatre',
  }
]
```

Would you be able to help me with this? Thank you in advance!

### Edit

@Rango's answer pointed me to the right direction! One caveat: [jsx-parser](https://github.com/RubyLouvre/jsx-parser) can not handle multiline components to which Rango's proposed the following solution:

```js
if (rsp.test(c)) continue; // add before /index.js:374
```

This however removes all whitespace from string attributes. So I've replaced it with this:

```js
if (/[\n\r]/.test(c)) continue; // this should remove lines only
```

So far this solution works. I would be more comfortable to use more stable libraries, but unfortunately none of the proposed solution worked for me (acorn-jsx, react-jsx-parser, babel/parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure that parsing JSX with regular expressions is efficient because curly brackets `{...}` can contain any JS expression, so if you choose this way then prepare to parse Javascript as well.

Fortunately, there are a bunch of JSX parsers that can do it for you. E.g. the first one I picked was [jsx-parser](https://github.com/RubyLouvre/jsx-parser) and this small beast can parse your example (with a simple trick). The shape of the result is quite different but you can transform it to match your needs.

```js
var test = `
---
title: Title of documents
tags: one, two, three
---

# My heading H1

Some text in paragraph. Than the list:
 - First item
 - Second item

More text with [a link](https://example.com).

<Articles category="theatre" count={3} />

Further text with more information.

<Newsletter categories={['theatre', 'design']} />

<MultilineComponent 
  paramA="A"
  paramB="B"
/>

<ComponentWithChildren param="value">
  Some children
</ComponentWithChildren>
`

const components = [...test.matchAll(/<[A-Z]/g)]
  .map(match => JSXParser(test.slice(match.index)))

document.getElementById('result').textContent = JSON.stringify(components, null, 2)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jsx-parser@1.0.8/index.umd.js"></script>

<pre id="result">Hello</pre>
```

*In my snippet I used UMD version of the package, but for node.js consider choosing ES module ofc.*

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! `jsx-parser` certainly does what I've asked for (even though it handles non-string props a bit weirdly, but I can live with that). 

This library seem not be maintained though - last commit 5 years ago, also no Typescript. Did you run into some more up to date solution? I've tried to google for more parsers, but was not able to find anything doing what this lib does.

Thank you!

Comment: There also were acorn-jsx, react-jsx-parser and babel/parser (which uses acorn under the hood) on the 1st page of search results. But these parsers output AST which has a more heavy structure. So that's why I took jsx-parser. Also, it doesn't require a true JSX file as input so it can process practically any non-JS string.

Comment: Actually, jsx-parser is a quite small package with a single export. There should not be a big problem converting it to TS, I guess.

Comment: Thank you Rango! I've found the libs you've mentioned as well, I was just a bit confused by their READMEs - there was no clear example of what I was trying to achieve in there. For the time being I'll use `jsx-parser`, maybe later I'll do some rewriting myself. Accepting the answer & happy christmas!

Comment: Thank you! BTW I noticed later that props were incorrectly parsed in MultilineComponent. To fix it you have to add a single line right before /index.js:374 - `if (rsp.test(c)) continue;` Merry holidays!